# How to create html with openfl?

Tags: haxe, openfl

I want to be able to fully adjust the width and height of the playing area. That is, I do not want to call the openfl test html5, but I want to create my own html and add openfl to it. (Like working on canvas)? How can i do it

Comment: or connect to html openfl

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom index.html template in `application.xml`, like so:

```xml
<template path="assets/index.html" rename="index.html" />
```

(also see [documentation](https://lime.software/docs/project-files/xml-format/#template))

Other option would be to embed the OpenFL application in an `<iframe>`.